# Get ORM class from schema instance in SQL alchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In SQL alchemy, you may do something like this to do a query:

```
model_instance = session.query(SomeModel).filter(SomeModel.value == some_value).first()
```

where `model_instance` is equivalent to some form of this, with data omitted:

```
model_instance = SomeModel( ... )
```

Let's suppose I want to create a function that could take multiple possible types for a `model_instance`, each with their own table. To do so, I want to do something like `type(model_instance)`, except instead of just getting a Python class, I want an object with the attribute `'_sa_instance_state'`, so I can do `session.query(SomeModel)`, given an instance `SomeModel()`.

For clarification, here is an example method (`save_model`):

```py
class Database:
    """SQLAlchemy object for interacting with the database"""

    def __init__(self, db_url: str):
        self.engine = create_engine(db_url)
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        self.session = Session()
    
    def save_model(self, model: Model) -> bool:
        """Saves given model to the database"""
        try:
            model_type = ... # Get the ORM class object from the model here
            if self.contains(model_type, **model.__dict__):
                return False
            self.session.add(model)
            self.session.commit()
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            self.session.rollback()
            raise Exception(f"Unable to save model: {str(e)}")
        return False

    def contains(self, model_class: Type[Model], **kwargs) -> bool:
        """Returns True if a model of the specified class with the given attributes exists in the database."""
        query = self.session.query(model_class)
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            query = query.filter(getattr(model_class, key) == value)
        return query.first() is not None
```

where `Model` is a union of schema types, each with their own separate table.

I tried doing something like this

```py
model_type = sqlalchemy.Table(model.__table__.name, model.__table__.metadata, autoload_with=self.engine)
```

and

```py
model_type = sqlalchemy.sql.text(model.__table__.name)
```

and

```
model_type = type(model)
```

But I still run into some variation of the following issue:

```
'Table' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

or

```
'TextClause' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

or

```
'SomeModel' has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

Sure, I could add in `model_class: Type[Model]` as another parameter to the `save_model` method, but I was wondering if it were possible to avoid doing that.

**Note**: `contains` works if you specify a specific model type, (e.g., `contains(SomeModel, param1="some_value")`, but not if you do `contains(type(model), param1="some_value")`).

Comment: The result of a query might not correspond to any specific table, since you can use joins and unions in the query.

Comment: I'm not looking to use joins or unions in the above example query. I'm looking to get the table for a given model instance

Comment: `model.__table__` is already an instance of `sa.Table`.

Comment: "I want a table object with the attribute '_sa_instance_state'" - I'm not sure what this means: `_sa_instance_state` is an attribute of ORM model instances, not tables.

Comment: @snakecharmerb My mistake on the terminology. I basically want the equivalent of `SomeModel`, given `SomeModel()`, so I can do `session.query(SomeModel)`

Comment: Would any of `sqlalchemy.inspect(some_model).mapper.class_`, `some_model.__class__` or `type(some_model)` work (all return the model class)?

Comment: No, they all fail with `'SomeModel' has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance's class can be obtained in any of these ways:

```py
sqlalchemy.inspect(some_model).mapper.class_

some_model.__class__

type(some_model)
```

however the problem is that in `contains`, the code iterates over the items in the instance's `__dict__` to create filters, but the instance has an `_sa_instance_state` attribute that does not exist on the model, so `getattr(ModelClass, '_sa_instance_state')` will raise an exception.

A simple solution would be to skip this attribute:

```py
for k, v in kwargs.items():
    if k = 'sa_instance_state':
        continue
    # Build the filter
```

A more sophisticated approach might be to check whether the attribute exists on the model before trying to create the filter:

```py
mapper = sqlalchemy.inspect(model_class)
for k, v kwargs.items():
    if k not in mapper.columns:
        continue
    # Build filter
```